Resetting values error on serial monitor using esp32 dev board
the uart serial monitor did not show the right values which i want to see. this error mostly occur when ever i am using Wi-Fi library.
showing these values:
Brownout detector was triggered
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13232
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4
expected simple serial printing of dh11 sensor data.

This line: Brownout detector was triggered means that input voltage of the ESP32 board dropped below acceptable levels. It indicates that whatever you're supplying the power to it (USB port?) is not capable of outputting as much current as the board requires. Try a USB hub with external power supply, or simply a differet USB port.

it makes sense, but trying a different USB cable solved the problem.

Good to hear, I have forgotten about crappy USB cables :)
